# Where can I find documentation on Berkeley Parser?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I consider using the Berkeley Parser in my research on parsing German since [some sources](http://aclweb.org/anthology/W/W08/W08-1008.pdf) propose it to be by far the best PCFG parser for this language. Unfortunatelly, we don't see any valuable documentation. Compared to Stanford Parser the Berkeley Parser's documentation is minimalistic.

Are there any information sources on training and tuning apart from its [Google Code Repository](https://code.google.com/p/berkeleyparser/), README and console help?

Comment: berkely's NLP work has always been sort of open but their documentation is sort of cryptic.

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted. Anyone who is going through the Google Code repository in search of this documentation is clearly putting in some serious effort. I did the same when I was using the Berkeley parser. I completely agree with what @2er0 says.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain more detail by run `java -jar berkeleyParser.jar` for using the Berkeley Parser

Comment: It is an obvious solution, but it doesn't add anything essential, we all read the help. Thank you anyway!